# Declaring maya api variables in cpp and h files

Tags: c++

On my header file I have my MDA variable:

```
class node : public MPxNode {

public:

    static MDoubleArray mDA;
};
```

Then on my .cpp file I see this line again:

```
MDoubleArray node::mDA;
```

- Is this line on the .cpp needed?

Comment: The line `static MDoubleArray mDA;` in the class is just a *declaration*. It tells the compiler that this variable exists, and what its type is. It doesn't actually create the variable or its memory. But `MDoubleArray node::mDA;` in the source file is a *definition*. It tells the compiler to actually create the variable, and make sure there's memory allocated for it. Any decent book, tutorial or class should have that information.